# Reload Page From Iframe in JS

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe and I want to refresh the main page through it. I've tried functions such as `window.location.reload()` etc.. but it seems it doesn't work.
I need to put the reload function on the iframe not on the main page.
I could get as much as `document.referrer` to get the main page.

**Iframe codesandbox**
[SEE THIS](https://codesandbox.io/s/cross-child-forked-zqdqmn?file=/index.html)

**Main page codesandbox** [SEE THIS](https://codesandbox.io/s/cross-origin-iframe-forked-bk1tr3?file=/index.html)

```
 <div class="iframe-container">
      <iframe class="iframe-layout" src="https://zqdqmn.csb.app/"></iframe>
  </div>
```

**Iframe Part**

```
  <script>
  
    function redirectToGoogle() {
      const mainUrl = document?.referrer

      window.location.href = `${mainUrl}`

      // window.open(mainUrl,"_self")
    }

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You can use [MessageEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event) and [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) for cross origin communication.

Comment: @Christopher. are you able to fork my codesandbox?

Comment: Sure, here is a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cross-origin-iframe-forked-92zerw?file=/index.html).

Comment: @Christopher. Thank you. you can put it as an answer and some explanation to it the `window.onmessage` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To interact with cross origin pages make us of [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) and [MessageEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event) using `onmessage` or `addEventListener("message", ...)`.

The [example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cross-origin-iframe-forked-92zerw?file=/index.html) shows how to make use with a specific origin, while this example here shows, how to handle it, if the target and/or source window have `'null'` as origin.

```js
window.addEventListener("message", async ({ data, origin, source }) => {
  // another check would be a check for the origin, but since the iframe was created with srcdoc, the origin is null
  console.log("Origin:",origin);
  // only react if the source window is the frame
  if (source == frameToListen.contentWindow) {
    try { // in case of "data == null"
      console.log("data", data);
      // wait for 5 seconds before reload
      if (data.reload) {
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r,5000));
        console.log("reload..?");
        window.location.reload();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
});

// Generate dummies in the iframe to send some events
// The only way to contact a window with an origin of "null" is by "*"
frameToListen.srcdoc = `<script>function send(obj) {
    window.parent.postMessage(obj, '*');
    // avoid unexpected end of input in stacksnippet-parser
  }</scr${""}ipt><input type="button" value="undefined" onclick="send()">
  <input type="button" value="null" onclick="send(null)">
  <input type="button" value="{ reload: true }" onclick="send({ reload: true })">
  <input type="button" value="{ reload: false }" onclick="send({ reload: false })">
  <input type="button" value="[]" onclick="send([])">`;
```

```html
<iframe id="frameToListen" style="width: 100%;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've seen `(data.type != "initialized")` in your codesandbox but not here. Is it necessary?

Comment: It is not really required, but there is no origin-check in my example and the codesandbox uses `window.parent.postMessage()` too, this just ignores their "ready" message.

Comment: Hi Christopher. what happens if you have two different functions. window.onmessage would only listen to one, right?

Comment: You can add multiple source, with `if (source == otherIFrame.contentWindow)` for example. Just add a separate check for another iframe. On the other side you can use `addEventListener` to define multiple listener with different targets.

Comment: The answer by Kaiido there just describes what I said. Use `addEventListener` for multiple listeners or `if/elseif` for one.

Comment: I also put my answer there and it seems to work. Is that good code?