# How to position an element inside an iframe with respect to parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position

I am working on a project where the content is loaded inside an iframe and the loader also present inside iframe, so when some action is performed the loader is positioned accoring to the height of iframe, but i want to show the loader based on the parent window, is there any way or hack to solve this problem.

This the css for the loader inside iframe
`.loaderIcon { position: fixed;top: 50%;left: 50%; }`

Comment: Not really. iFrames are essentially embedded windows.

Answer (score 0):

If the site within the iframe should be allowed to manipulate the content of the parent window, there are some workarounds, but as mentioned in the comments, it is not possible for elements from the iframes to be displayed relative at the parent window.

You can use `window.parent` from within the iframe and create/modify every element on the hosting site, but **only** if the iframe is following the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Based on the site `http://example.com/` these would be allowed to modify the parent.

| URL | SOP | Info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `http://example.com/iframe.html` | **Yes** | Same protocol, host and port |
| `http://example.com/dir/inner.html` | **Yes** | Same protocol, host and port |
| `https://example.com/secure.html` | *No* | Other protocol |
| `http://example.com:81/dir/etc.html` | *No* | Other port |
| `http://subdomain.example.com/dir/other.html` | *No* | Other host |

If the iframe is loaded from a different origin, you can use [`window.parent.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send custom events to the page hosting the iframe and capture the [`Message Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event) to handle it on the parent window and allow everything you want. [MessageEvent Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72695566/10304804)

Comment: Thank you Christopher will try this